# How to compile all the c files in given directory?

Tags: bash, terminal

I want to compile all the files in a given directory.

I don't want to use

```
gcc -o main file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp ...
```

because there are many files.

So how do I compile all the files whose extension is .cpp in a given directory using terminal/bash?

Comment: Just compile them, or also link into an executable?

Comment: Stating a desire is not a question.

Comment: `*.c` expands to all the .c files in the current directory. And you might want `"$somedir"/*.c` for some other directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are asking for files with extension .cpp? So you can just type:

gcc -o main *.cpp

The shell expand the asterisk to file1.cpp, file2.cpp and so on of the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using Mac / Linux:

1. CD into the directory of your .c file: `cd /path/tofile/`.
2. Congrats! You are in the directory of your .cpp file. Just type (or copy and paste) this- `gcc -o main file.cpp`- to compile one file, or this - `gcc -o main *.cpp` for all files
3. If that was successful, just run the program with `./main`, or whatever you named your executable.

Hope this works for you!

Comment: what if i don't know the name of files in directory?                                                or                                                      What if there are too many files to compile in that directory then writing the names of all the files won't be a good way solving the problem.I want to compile c++ files not c files (I know that I have to use g++ instead of g--)

Comment: I answered your question before you said you wanted to compile C++ files, and you said you wanted to compile C files...... you don't have to compile using g++ - g++ will compile all files as C++ regardless of extension, while gcc is more flexible; will compile based on extension. Check my edit!